# Disable ctrl+C on ssh batch code

Tags: windows-10, ssh, batch, openssh, ctrl

I'm running an SSH server on windows 10 that autoruns a batch script. I'm trying to keep users from exiting out of the batch script and attaining access to the system. However the user can just enter ctrl+c and it will exit out of the batch script and give the user full access to the computer. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible (kind of). But its far away from trivial task. Please check this [Q/A in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31445330/2908599) about the subject

> It turns out that (GOTO) 2>NUL behaves almost identically to EXIT /B,
>   except concatenated commands within an already parsed block of code
>   are still executed after the effective return, within the context of
>   the CALLer!

Comment: Windows. No bash. It’s windows.

Comment: @MarkDeven, edited :)